# In a data warehouse, should a measure be based on a fact or a dimension?

Tags: data-warehouse, olap, dimensional-modeling

Let's say there is a data warehouse created from a shop data. A fact is a single purchase of a product. There is a dimension that describes a customer.

There is a need to create a measure that stores a number of distinct customers. Can this measure be created based on customer identifier in the dimension table, or it needs to be fact table? In which cases one or the other solution is better?

Below I post a visualization based on an *AdventureWorks2016* database:

[image: Data warehouse example visualization based on a AdventureWorks2016 database.]

Comment: The dimension is typically understod as a number of unique *active* customers in some time interval, i.e. it is derived from the fact table.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Are there situations where it would be different? When? Why would someone go with the different apporach?

Comment: Simple example - you have 1M customers in `dim_customers`, but only 800K of them *made a sales transaction in the last month* and 950K in the *last year*. The smaller figures are must more interesant than the larger one.